# Oracle Format non date To Date in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

Ho do we convert string with not date format to date format in oracle, i have date like this in my table

```
04082014
```

and i wanna make these string into date format like

```
2014-08-04 or with format yyyy-mm-dd
```

how do we do that in oracle ?
if using the built in function in oracle like

```
TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyy-mm-dd') or TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

can we use that format for between querys ? and what about peformance with huge data when we use that fungction ?

i just wanna know the peformance if using that function in huge data, and why when i using between function like

```
select * from PAID WHERE PDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('04082014','DDMMYYYY') AND TO_DATE('05082014','DDMMYYYY')
```

and the result is

```
[Err] ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the appropriate format for `TO_DATE()`:

```
TO_DATE('04082014', 'DDMMYYYY')
```

(Assuming the date is 2014-08-04.)

Oracle stores dates in an internal format.  If you want them in a particular format for output purposes, to `TO_CHAR()`, not `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: so if i wanna using between function i would use `BETWEEN TO_DATE('04082014', 'DDMMYYYY') AND TO_DATE('05082014', 'DDMMYYYY')` or there is another way to do that

Comment: I would write that as `BETWEEN DATE '2014-08-04' and DATE '2014-08-05'`, because I have a strong preference for ANSI-standard dates.

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE` is used to convert string literal into `DATE`.  Oracle stores date in internal format which consists of 7 bytes.

`TO_CHAR` is used to convert DATE into string literal for display purpose.

Both the conversion requires a proper format mask.

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('04082014', 'DDMMYYYY') AND TO_DATE('05082014', 'DDMMYYYY')
```

is same as,

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2014-08-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2014-08-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You could have any combination of the day, month and year format. You won't hit the error `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` as long as you take care of the correct format of the literal value and the format mask.